# Does hibernate store db model as singleton?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing a java application and access my data through hibernate. I am in doubt whether hibernate stores each db model as singleton.

For example, the line of code below executed in two different threads

```
Book book = bookRepository.finOne(1);
```

will return the same instance of object or two different ones?

Comment: The statement you show gives you _one_ instance, neither _the same_ nor _two different_.

Comment: No it's not a singleton you will end up with different object referencing the same row, session/entity manager are not thread safe and concurrency depends on db isolation level

Comment: I asked in a case this statement executed in 2 different theards